# How to know content provider database column name form another app[Content resolver]

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am new to android. I have one doubt in Content provide and resolver. I have my custom content provider app and i want to access its database from another app.I have created uri and had given authorise in manifest. While inserting new value from another[Content Resolver] how will my resolver app know column names of contentprovider because we have to create ContentValues Object and there column name is required while inserting data... Please help

Answer (score 1):

If the third party app is making their ContentProvider public, they probably have a documentation on how to access it, otherwise you should contact the app's author.

Otherwise, you can use a null projection querying data from the  same content provider and print all the columns in the cursor you retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach in implementation of `ContentProvider` is to create additional "contract" class which encapsulates all information needed for communication with the `ContentProvider` (whether this `ContentProvider` exported or not).

If your `ContentProvider` should be accessible from other applications, you export it and publish the respective "contract" class to clients (e.g. publish JavaDoc on website, send by mail, etc.).

Example of "contract" class found in AOSP is `ContactsContract` class. Its JavaDoc is being published [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html). Its source can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/provider/ContactsContract.java).